# Storing passwords in a Hashed format

Tags: java, hash, passwords, storage, hmac

In my application, users create data then use their secret key to calculate a hash. The data with the appended hash are sent to the server.

The server recalculates the hash using the private key it has listed for the user.

Now, on the server's side, I obviously can't store the secret key in plain-text. However, I also can't do a one way store using Hmac, because then, when I recalculate the hash on the data, it will give a different response.

What is the best way to store user's secret password on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is what you are doing now. I mean the password is never stored either as plain text nor in encrypted reversable form. I did not exactly understand your problem but if you want to make the system truly secure find solution for your problem without using user's password in plain form.

But if you indeed need this I'd recommend you at least to store passwords in DB encrypted. The encryption password should be also hidden somehow to make potential hacker's work harder. But note: once you do it the system becomes breakable and all depends only on the hacker's professional skills and motivation.

Comment: The password is stored in plain text on the server side -- I recalculate the hash once the request reaches the server using the user's plain text password as the "key". (Just to make sure that the user's calculated hash matches the server's calculated hash for the particular request). Is there something that I am missing conceptually?